# Question about the algebraic structure of function space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, function-spaces

So, on the linear algebra class it is mentioned that function space is an example of the vector space.

By the definition of the vector space, any vector space $(V,+,\cdot)$ both an abelian group and a module. That means the function space has two operators working on a set. So far is correct, right?

One is the scalar multiplication $c\cdot f$ and one is the addition of functions $f+g$.

But in calculus we have seen that there are also many other operators that can work on function, for instance, the multiplication of functions $f\times g$ and the function composition $f\circ g$, also there are unary operators such as differential operator $\nabla$ and integral operator $\int$ and integral transformations $T f$, those are all linear, right?

*[Main question]* Does this means there are some more complex algebra structure for the function space? If not, how does the function composition enrolled into the discussion.

Decomposing the main question:

Part 1: If I obtain a function space with certain basis. It is closed under scalar multiplication and function addition because it is a vector space. Now, if I attach function composition to this structure, make it
$$
(F, \cdot, +, \circ)=(\text{set of function, scalar product, addition, function composition}),
$$
is the set still closed? Is there a proof or counter example for this.

---

*[The question is explained by @RyanHowe in comment]* Also, in wiki it is mentioned that function space is also a topological space idea. What's the difference when we treat the function space differently? Is the definition changed?

---

Does that means we only care scalar multiplication $c\cdot f$ and addition of functions $f+g$ in **linear algebra**. And, differential operator $\nabla$ and integral operator $\int$ are considered in **Calculus**?

Thank you guys very much.

Comment: The additional structure is a metric space probably. For instance look at the space of continuous functions. (https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1415/math3060/Chapter%203.%20Continuous%20Functions.pdf).

Comment: The additional structure in the metric space have to be binary operator, right? How could differential and integral operator form a metric space?

Comment: You can view them as linear operators between spaces of functions but you have to be specific about the classes of functions. There are different ideas of how integration works. For instance the Lp spaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space). Integration takes a function and gives you another one.

Comment: A vector space by itself doesn't work. They need to be complete normed vector spaces. Metrics induce norms and the metric itself induces a topology.

Comment: Thank you very much, that answers half of my questions. But I still confused by those operators that are not metric and not scalar multiplication and also not addition. Doesn't the function composition $f\circ g$ a nonlinear operator?

Comment: It's just, if I obtain a function space with certain basis (for example, $e^x$ and $sin(x)$ and polynomial). It is closed under scalar multiplication and function addition because it is a vector space. Now, if I attach function composition to this structure, is the set still closed? Is there a proof or counter example for this.

Comment: It probably depends. The composition of polynomials is another polynomial. I'm not sure in general. You generally have to be very specific about the types of functions..i.e all bounded periodic functions which are piecewise continuous or something.

Comment: I will put my questions to the content, than you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if we have some algebraic structure $R$, the set of functions $f : A \to R$ inherit all the algebraic structure that $R$ has. For example, if $R$ is an Abelian group, the function space $\{f : A \to R\}$ inherits the group operations from $R$.

So $\{f : A \to \mathbb{R}\}$ in particular will inherit the structure of $\mathbb{R}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. This means that not only can we multiply a function by a scalar, but we can also multiply a function by another function.

As for function composition, this is only a useful operation when $A = \mathbb{R}$. And it doesn't play very nice with the other operations for the most part. So you could come up with an "algebraic structure" by saying things like $(f \cdot g) \circ h = (f \circ h) \cdot (g \circ h)$, for instance. But there isn't a nice name for it.

Finally, consider that differentiation (and even integration) aren't total operators. They rely on the function being continuous. But if you're interested in looking into the algebraic structure of differentiation, you should look into [differential algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Since the algebraic structure of function $f:A\to R$ can inherit from $R$. And you mentioned function composition is only useful in $\mathbb{R}$, does this means function composition corresponding to some real number operation? If so, what is it?

Comment: @ZizhengYang All I meant by that is if we have two functions $f, g : A \to \mathbb{R}$, the composite $f \circ g$ is not usually defined. Composition only makes sense at all if $A = \mathbb{R}$.